# Shorthand for nested null checking C#

Tags: c#, language-features

As far as I know there is not a **significantly** more elegant way to write the following....

```
string src;
if((ParentContent!= null)
    &&(ParentContent.Image("thumbnail") != null)
    &&(ParentContent.Image("thumbnail").Property("src") != null))
    src = ParentContent.Image("thumbnail").Property("src").Value
```

**Do you think there should be a C# language feature to make this shorter?**
**And if so, what should it look like?**
for example, something like extending the ?? operator

```
string src = ParentContent??.Image("thumbnail")??.Property("src")??.Value;
```

Apologies for the rather contrived example, and my over-simplified solution.

**Edit ... Many years later**
This is now a planned language feature called the "**Null propagating operator**"  `?.`
https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883 ( Thanks @Brian )

Comment: Definitely appeals to my sweet tooth!

Comment: See https://roslyn.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Language%20Feature%20Status&referringTitle=Documentation and https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883 .  This feature should be available soon.

Comment: It's coming in C# 6!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no built-in syntax for doing this, but you can define an extension method to do this:

```
R NotNull<T, R>(this T src, Func<T, R> f) 
    where T : class where R : class {
  return src != null ? f(src) : null;
}
```

Now, you can rewrite your example as follows:

```
src = ParentContent.NotNull(p => p.Image("thumbnail")).
        NotNull(i => i.Property("src")).NotNull(src => src.Value);
```

It is not as nice as it may be with a syntactic support, but I'd say it's much more readable.

Note that this adds the `NotNull` method to all .NET types, which may be a bit inconvenient. You could solve that by defining a simple wrapper type `WrapNull<T> where T : class` containing only a value of type `T` and a method for turning any reference type into `WrapNull` and providing the `NotNull` in the `WrapNull` type. Then the code would look like this:

```
src = WrapNull.Wrap(ParentContent).NotNull(p => p.Image("thumbnail")).
        NotNull(i => i.Property("src")).NotNull(src => src.Value);
```

(So you wouldn't pollute the IntelliSense of every type with the new extension method)

With a bit more effort, you could also define a LINQ query operators for doing this. This is a bit overkill, but it is possible to write this (I won't include the definitions here as they are a bit longer, but it's possible in case someone is interested :-)).

```
src = from p in WrapNull.Wrap(ParentContent)
      from i in p.Image("thumbnail").
      from src in i.Property("src")
      select src.Value;
```

Comment: I have to say, I had to read that about 5 times to properly grok it.  Sometimes reading Functional code makes me regret starting out with procedural style languages instead of say LISP.  Other days, I thank my sanity I didn't! :D

Comment: @Serapth: I think that one thing is reading the implementation (and understanding how it works) and another thing is reading the user-code. Explaining how to use my `NotNull` extension method shouldn't be that difficult (maybe I just didn't do as good job here :-)).

Comment: Oh no, I agree completely.  Actually using the extension method is a no brainer and is completely legible, much more so even that the original posts recommended solution.  It's the extension method itself that is horrifically difficult for me to read.  That said, functional programming is not naturally intuitive to me and truth told, I have always found templated code adds a layer of confusion to the scenario as well.  I think it is just how my brain is wired.  I understand the syntax, what is happening and how it works, I just have to read it again and again to follow how it works.

Comment: The only caveat about this is that it doesn't actually behave quite the same way as a bunch of nested `if` statements or ternary operators; *all* of the wrapper methods in the chain will actually be executed, even if the lambdas aren't.  That's probably not going to a problem most of the time, but it's something to keep in mind - this is not a short-circuit evaluator.

Comment: @Aaronaught: You can nest them: `a.NotNull(b => b.Foo.NotNull(c => c.Bar))` - then it behaves exactly like nested ifs. (I thought that the non-nested use would be more readable for the introduction)

Comment: Such a dilema, your answer has more cool stuff in it, but Aaronaught answers the actual question a little more.

Answer (score 16):

It's been suggested and apparently rejected by the team:

[A bit more C# syntactic sugar for nulls](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/192177/a-bit-more-c-syntactic-sugar-for-nulls)

The proposed syntax would have looked like `a.?b.?c()` - very useful, and unambiguous.

I'd really like to see it too, but doesn't look like it'll happen.  Maybe if enough people vote on it!

Answer (score 15):

We considered it for C# 4 but did not have the budget. It's a nice feature that a lot of people request, so perhaps we'll get it into a future hypothetical language version. No promises.

Comment: Someday, Eric will have had a long day and will be too tired.  And on that day, he'll say, "we are considering this for the next version of C#."

Comment: @Jack: I'm not the person to do the considering anymore, sorry!

Comment: Noooooooooooooooooooooooo

Answer (score 1):

Correct me, if I am wrong, but this could be solved using C# 6.0's [null-conditional operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx):

```
string src = ParentContent?.Image("thumbnail")?.Property("src")?.Value;
```

If `src` is already in used before this value assignment, you could use it as follows:

```
string src = ....;

// ...

src = ParentContent?.Image("thumbnail")?.Property("src")?.Value ?? src;

// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

It still leaves a bit to be desired but I'd write it like this:

```
var src = ParentContent == null ? null
    : ParentContent.Image("thumbnail") == null ? null
    : ParentContent.Image("thumbnail").Property("src") == null ? null
    : ParentContent.Image("thumbnail").Property("src").Value;
```