# Null arrays and IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, arrays, null, ienumerable, null-coalescing-operator

[A previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5640369/ienumerablet-null-coalescing-extension) discusses IEnumerable and the convention of using empty collections instead of null valued ones. It is a good practice as it does away with many mistake-prone null checks.

But the answers don't quite address one of the cases. Many times I'm *forced* to deal with null values, specifically when arrays are returned from foreign methods. An example:

```
(foreignObj.GetPeople() ?? Enumerable.Empty<Person>())
  .Where(p => p.Name != "John")
  .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
  .Take(4);
```

I've written a helper method which does improve readability somewhat.

```
public class SafeEnumerable
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> From<T>(T[] arr)
    {
        return arr ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

```
SafeEnumerable.From(foreignObj.GetPeople())
  .Where(p => p.Name != "John")
  .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
  .Take(4);
```

I don't mind this, but I'm looking for better ideas. It seems like I'm adding something that should be there already.

Comment: In the specific case of `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()`, you should not even need a null check or the `??` operator. That method isn't known to return null if no files are found, it returns an empty `FileInfo[]` array. So it's covered by the accepted answer to your linked question too.

Comment: I 've done the same, only as an `EmptyIfNull<T>` extension method: `foo.EmptyIfNull()....`

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I've edited the question to include a fictive example instead.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831439/shorthand-for-nested-null-checking-c#answer-2831475

Answer (score 2):

The problem locates where you got the collection(`IEnumerable<T>`). If you are always busy with checking for `null` values of a collection, you should consider to modify the source. For example:

```
public User GetUser(long id) { }
public List<User> GetUsers(long companyId) { }
```

The first method makes sense if it returns a `null` when no user is found, a `null` return value means *not found*. But the second method, in my opinion, should never return a `null` in any normal circumstance. If no users found, an empty list should be returned, instead of a `null` value, which means **something of the program is incorrect**. And the given example in your question, I don't believe `directoryInfo.GetFiles("*.txt")` returns null if no `txt` file is found, instead it should return an empty collection.

Comment: Thanks, I was mistaken about GetFiles so modified the question which is general anyway. However, it is specifically about foreign methods that can't be changed.

Comment: @CÅdahl: I think I'm answering the question you are asking :)

Comment: I agree with the list part, but I think `GetUser` should get a user, or die trying.  If you want to write a getter-style method that fails without throwing an exception, it should have the signature `public bool TryGetUser(long id, out User result) { }`.

Comment: @DannyChen: Hm. Your answer is to modify the source, which I can not do (since it's a foreign method/class/interface). I agree that it's better to return an empty collection, but other than explicitly wrapping the foreign interface this isn't possible. Perhaps that **would** be cleaner?

Answer (score 2):

I have created a series of extension methods for IEnumerable, the first of which being EmptyIfNull

eg.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions {

  public static IEnumerable<T> EmptyIfNull<T>(this IEnumerable<T> collection) {
    return collection ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
  }

}
```

this allows me to do

```
var q = foreignObj.GetPeople().EmptyIfNull().Where(p=>p.Name != "John").OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(4);
```

I have then added "Safe" extensions so I can make the code a little shorter to type/easier to read

e.g.

```
 public static IEnumberable<T> SafeWhere<T>(this collection<T> source,Func<T,bool> predicate) {
   return source==null ? Enumerable.Empty<T>() : source.Where(predicate);
 }
```

giving

```
var q = foreignObj.GetPeople().SafeWhere(p=>p.Name != "John").OrderBy(p => p.Name).Take(4);
```

Comment: I like this, with the same reservation as LukeH's answer. Also, the Safe-prefixed wrappers seem very arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify the source to correct the method that returns null then your approach makes sense.

You could perhaps make it an extension method so that it can be used in a more idiomatic, LINQy way:

```
var query = foreignObj.GetPeople()
                      .AsNonNullEnumerable()
                      .Where(p => p.Name != "John")
                      .OrderBy(p => p.Name)
                      .Take(4);

// ...

public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<T> AsNonNullEnumerable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source)
    {
        return source ?? Enumerable.Empty<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's okay technically, but seems inconsistent. While calling an extension method on a null value **can** work, it does not for many extension methods in LINQ (they decide to throw). That's the premise of the question, actually. :)

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately I don't think that there is anything built-in for this. Unless you repeat yourself:

```
foreach(var item in (GetUsers() ?? new User[0])) // ...
```

A slightly 'better' implementation (taking example from what the C# compiler generates for the `yield return` sytnax), which is **marginally** less wastefuly with memory:

```
class SafeEnumerable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IEnumerator<T>
{
    private IEnumerable<T> _enumerable;
    public SafeEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable) { _enumerable = enumerable; }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (_enumerable == null)
            return this;
        else
            return _enumerable.GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() { return GetEnumerator(); }

    public T Current { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }
    object System.Collections.IEnumerator.Current { get { throw new InvalidOperationException(); } }

    public bool MoveNext() { return false; }
    public void Reset() { }
    public void Dispose() { }
}
```

Comment: You've just re-invented `Enumerable.Empty`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341042.aspx

Comment: As LukeH says, isn't this just Enumerable.Empty?

Comment: @LukeH d'oh, you learn something new every day. The `SafeEnumerable` still has merit though.