# What advantages or disadvantages would the ?= operator have?

Tags: c#, language-features

I'm thinking instead of

```
result = result ?? defaultValue;
```

you could write

```
result ?= defaultValue;
```

I'm not saying it's a good idea.
What advantages would this operator have?
What disadvantages would this operator have?

Comment: What issues would it address?

Comment: Only if you want to obfuscate your code.

Comment: does += address an issue?

Comment: @TimSchmelter: It's not exactly an unheard-of pattern.  `+=`, `-=`, `*=`

Comment: I consider `??` to already be a shorthand operator for the longer `result = result != null ? result : defaultValue`.

Comment: An interesting question...but in the wrong place.

Comment: could this be made Constructive? (I'll try) anyway @JaredPar managed to get something constructive in his answer, if not in my question ;-)

Comment: I think it would be useful just too rarely to justify itself. Where could it be used? Lazy initialization of singletons perhaps? `theThing ?= new Thing(); return theThing;` .. but we can already do: `return theThing ?? (theThing = new Thing());`

Comment: Asking for the potential advantages of such a feature is much more in line with what stackoverflow is expecting.  If you edited your question to reflect that stance (completely edit, not just add a by line), it's much more likely to be reopened

Comment: If we're going after new null coalescing operators, I'd ask for a member (field, property, or method) null coalescing operator.  E.g., something like `Instance.?Field` means (`Instance == null ? null : Instance.Field`).  Great for cases where you want chaining but could encounter a `null` in the chain.

Comment: @Brian I asked that question also. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831439/shorthand-for-nested-null-checking-c-sharp

Answer (score 7):

The greatest potential advantage i see is the ability for it to provide the same advantages of other compound operators like `+=`.  Consider the following

```
Method().Field = Method().Field ?? someValue;
```

If `Method()` is expensive or has side effects, these will occur twice for this statement.  In order to prevent this from happening you'd need to break this up into 2 lines

```
var temp = Method();
temp.Field = temp.Field ?? someValue;
```

This can be a bit tedious if you get stuck in this position.  If `?=` had the same guarantees of `+=` that the side effects of the left hand side only happened once then this extra line wouldn't be necessary.

```
Method().Field += someValue; // Method() happens once
Method().Field ?= someValue; // Method() happens once
```

IMHO that is the key advantage that is provided by having a `?=` operator over simply `??`.  It would be valuable, but I don't think it would be worth adding to the language

Answer (score 4):

This has been suggested before, and I based my 2011 April Fool's Day blog post on taking this idea to the extreme:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/04/01/compound-assignment-part-two.aspx

Unlike all the other operators mentioned in that post, `??=` would actually be a little bit useful. It would not be useful enough to justify its "direct" costs -- designing and implementing and documenting and all that costs time and effort and money. And it certainly would not justify its "opportunity" costs -- the time, effort and money spent on doing a rather silly and not particularly useful operator could be spent on features that directly address real problems that developers actually have.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's worth it.  Generally, you would almost always do something like:

```
result = someSourceValue ?? defaultValue;
```

Your second form is a special case, and would rarely be used.

The null coalescing operator is most useful when reading values from some source, like a web service, and you want to force missing values to zero or some other default.  The data is almost always going to be coming from somewhere, and going somewhere else.

Comment: As a moderator I'm really shocked that you bothered to answer this. It's clearly just a polling question and not constructive; there can be no **answer** to this question. It should have been closed immediately.

Comment: The horror. . .

Answer (score 0):

Probably not. I've only used the null coalescing operator a handful of times in C#, and never like this. The C# way of doing things is to write explicit null checks, not willy-nilly assignment. (No offense)

I'm sure many people would like to have this operator, but I don't think it would benefit the language at all.

That's just my opinion though.

Comment: The null coalescing operator is useful when reading values from some source, like a web service, and you want to force missing values to zero, or somesuch.

Comment: I agree. So many people don't understand `??` or `?:` so why add `?=` into the mix?