# Best way to check for null for multi child object

Tags: c#, linq

I would like to test for null to avoid exception. I receive list of objects which i have to export to excel and display in [Grid.Mvc](https://gridmvc.codeplex.com/)

**Excel export:**

```
sheet.Cells["A" + i].Value = item.Car.Door.Code; //FLCo
```

**Grid display:**

```
columns.Add(c => c.Car.Door.Code).Titled("FLCo");
```

The thing is **Car** can be null, **Door** can be null.

> Q1: For the excel export, my solution is to use a couple of `if/else` (any
>   better way)?
>
> For the Grid display: `if/else` or "?" operator is not supported
>   inside the linq

the following will generate error

```
columns.Add(c => c.Car==null?"":(c.Car.Door==null?"":c.Car.Code)).Titled("FLCo");
```

**error:**

> Cannot convert lambda expression to type
>   'GridMvc.Columns.IGridColumn' because it is not a
>   delegate

**Q2: Any idea how to solve this?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorthand for nested null checking C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2831439/shorthand-for-nested-null-checking-c-sharp)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using C#6 (which is included in VS2015, thanks HimBromBeere.), you can write it as followed:

```
sheet.Cells["A" + i].Value = item?.Car?.Door?.Code;
```

If any of the properties is NULL, the result will be NULL.

Comment: This is a feature of C#6, not .NET. However the language comes only on VS2015 which usually is used on .NET 4.6. You could use this feature also on .NET 2.0 when using VS2015. Anyway nice answer.

Comment: Null propagation operator or "Elvis operator" on of the best syntax sugar in C#

Answer (score 2):

As for **Q2**: You can use `statement lambda`s by enclosing the statement in curly braces: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/bb397687.aspx#Anchor_1

So in your case it would be

```
columns.Add(c => {c.Car==null?"":(c.Car.Door==null?"":c.Car.Code)}).Titled("FLCo");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use ["Elvis operator"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jerrynixon/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator/). Or if not supported I prefer to use extension methods.

```
public static class Maybe
{
    public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluetor)
        where TInput : class
        where TResult : class
    {
        return o == null ? null : evaluetor(o);
    }

    public static TResult Return<TInput, TResult>
        (this TInput o, Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator, TResult failureValue)
        where TInput : class
    {
        return o == null ? failureValue : evaluator(o);
    }
}
```

So in code you can just do something like

```
sheet.Cells["A" + i].Value = item.With(x => x.Car).With(x => x.Door).Return(x => x.Code, "null");
```